# Create many-to-one (n:1) / one-to-one (1:1) relationship with JDBI 3

Tags: java, jdbi

Topic says it all: I have a 1:1 relationship, which is technically a many-to-one relationship, but I would expect both to be handled the same. The relationship is a status column that holds primary keys of another table with status codes. The SQL query could not be more simple:

```
SELECT * FROM User LEFT OUTER JOIN status USING (status_id)
```

All the JDBI examples I could find with regards to join seem to expect considerably more complicated joins with `CollectionS`, whereas I simply want to get back `UserS` that look like this:

```
class User {
    String name;
    Status status;
}

class Status {
    int code;
}
```

In this example, the tables would be `User(VARCHAR name, INT status_id)`, `Status(INT status_id, INT code)`.

As a bonus follow up question, the status codes are (relatively) static, so it seems like a good idea to generate an enum class matching the `Status` table. I saw JDBI comes with an `EnumMapper`, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: "Topic says it all" - to be honest, without your explanation I'd not understand your topic ;)

Comment: Which of the approaches described on http://jdbi.org/#_joins did you try? Does it work?

Comment: I don't know JDBI but if you want to get users I'd say you need to state so in your select part, i.e. instead of `SELECT * ...` I'd try `SELECT user.* FROM User user ...`

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank all of the approaches are about one-to-many relationships, so none of them apply to my issue, which is the problem.

Comment: One-to-many should easily be transformed into many-to-one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution turned out to be the @Nested annotation. For future reference I'm posting a working version of the example:

```
class User {
    String name;

    @Nested("status")
    Status status;
}

class Status {
    int code;
}

interface Dao {
    @SqlQuery("SELECT user.*, status.code AS `status_code` FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN Status USING (status_id)
    @RegisterBeanMapper(User.class)
    List<User> getUsers();
}
```

Note that while in this example, I have been explicit with the name of the joined table, but I didn't have to be. If you have no overlapping column names, then the example can be simplified to:

```
class User {
    String name;

    @Nested
    Status status;
}

class Status {
    int code;
}

interface Dao {
    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN Status USING (status_id)
    @RegisterBeanMapper(User.class)
    List<User> getUsers();
}
```

Lastly, if you use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for your data classes, the correct syntax is one of the following (depending on whether you need the explicit column renaming):

```
@Data
class User {
    String name;

    @Setter(onMethod = @__(@Nested))
    Status status;
}
```

or

```
@Data
class User {
    String name;

    @Setter(onMethod = @__(@Nested("status")))
    Status status;
}
```

Comment: Note for the Lombok part: BeanMapper will honor a nested annotation on either the getter or the setter.

Comment: @qualidafial But not on the field, what forces to use this ridiculous `@__` syntax, when Lombok is in the game.

Comment: Lombok 1.18.4 added a new lombok.config option `lombok.copyableAnnotations` that you can use to avoid the `@__` stuff.